# understanding file handle and csv reader for python

Tags: python, csv

Can someone help me understand the behavior when we use csv.reader - Apparently in the second instance of csv.reader within same function handle seems to be coming out empty. Can someone please explain me operation/reason ?

```
def getAllCategories(self, file):
    csvread = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvread:
        print row[3]

    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row1 in reader:
        print " -------------- "
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are reading over the same file twice? There may be a better way to do what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - I agree to the part there would be better way but unfortunately I am not able to. From this link I am getting a csv file and trying to get all categories, say Family based/Employment based and all and once I have that I want to key a dictionary with each category as key and all those subtypes as its values. Should I post a separate question for it ?  https://www.uscis.gov/tools/reports-studies/immigration-forms-data/data-set-all-uscis-application-and-petition-form-types

Comment: You should definitely post a new question because there is a very simple way to solve that problem that doesn't involve reading over the file twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `file` are already consumed by the first reader. Once `csvread` reads all the rows it moves the file pointer to the end of file thus there's nothing left to read for second reader.

You could use [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to move file pointer back to the beginning of file before creating the second reader:

```
file.seek(0)
```